# Creating abstract test in Intern js

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, coded-ui-tests, intern

In the application I am working on for UI testing with `intern`. There are certain modules that have similar components and functions. So I'm trying to figure out the way to create an `Abstract test` for those components so that I don't have to repeat the same code for all those modules. Can someone throw some light on how to create abstract tests (like in `java`) which I can extend or something to other test with similar kind of functionalities?

Comment: Is this about https://theintern.github.io/ ?

Comment: yes it is about  theintern.github.io .

Answer (score 1):

I am not that much familiar with intern.js. But I've worked in webdriver.io - with Mocha.
In that, achieved the abstract tests by created custom modules for the commonly used functions(for example, populating the input test data email id) and imported the modules in individual tests wherever it required.